# Javascript and Ajax function not working

Tags: javascript, ajax, forms

I am trying to update my database when the user clicks a certain link (links have different values, so when user clicks one link number goes up by 1, another by 2, and so on).

I need to submit a form to another page containing the data from `#form` with a variable behind it, but this function doesn't seem to be working.

**JavaScript**

```
function update_number(x) {

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "update_likes.php",
        data: $("#Form"+x).serialize(),
        dataType: "json",

        return false;
        };
```

**HTML**

```
<input type='image' src='...' onclick'update_number(2);' />
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: what have you tried so far? this looks like a copy / paste code and that you do not know javascript at all. this place is not for teaching you how to properly code. its for giving answers to true questions.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your JavaScript is not closed correctly.

*Try changing your JavaScript with this:*

```
function update_number(x) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "update_likes.php",
        data: $("#Form"+x).serialize(),
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(json) {
            alert( json );
            return false;
        }
    });
 }
```